# Java how to extract audio stream from movie

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I need to extract the audio stream from a movie and eventually convert it to a certain format, let's say MP3 at 192 kbps, for later processing, more exactly to detect the voices.

Are there any libraries for extracting the audio stream from a movie?

Answer (score 0):

you could use mplayer to extract audio to a seperate file:

mplayer yourmovie.mov -vo null -vc null -ao pcm:fast

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html

Comment: I need a Java library if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a DVD it can be as simple as stripping the audio track, which you can do with various bits of DVD ripping software.
It it has a standard Dolby Digital audio track (up to 48kHz 16bit) or possibly TrueHD in the case of Blu-Ray (up to 96kHz, 24bit) you should be able to decode either using either **mplayer** or **ffmpeg**.

If it's Java you're interested in check out FMJ:

http://fmj-sf.net/index.php

This provides a Java wrapper to ffmpeg.